# Targeting the parent div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parent-child

So, here's my situation. I have a wordpress site, and each entry has a link within the post div.

```
<div class="post" id="post-133"> 
<h2><a href="post-link" rel="bookmark" title="Link to Post">Post</a></h2> 
<div class="post-date"> 
<span class="date">Tuesday, Jan. 26, 2010</span><span class="right read"><a href="#" class="noprint show_single" id="133">Read More</a></span> 
</div>
```

I have the height applied to the css to only show a certain amount of each post. How can I get jQuery to target the parent element to add a class, showing the whole post? Here is what I have so far. Am I on the right path?

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var curr = (event.target).parent('div');
$j(function() {
  $j('a.show_single').click(function() {
 $j('curr').toggleClass('show');
 return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the event function, you use the `this` keyword to get into the proper context, and then you traverse through the DOM to find what you are looking for:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
    $j('a.show_single').click(function() {
        $j(this).parents('div.post').toggleClass('show');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j(function() {
     $j('a.show_single').click(function() {
        $j(this).parents('div.post').toggleClass('show');
        return false;
     });
 });
```

Comment: This won't do anything, since the `a` element's direct parent is a `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

Assuming that you want to toggle the `show` class of the `div.curr` containing the `a` that was clicked on, you can call the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method, like this:

```
$j(this).closest('div.curr').toggleClass('show');
```